# How can I add mouseover descriptions to nodes on a networkx diagram?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to create a skill tree using networkx, but due to the length of descriptions, it's not feasible to have permanent labels/annotations with the ability descriptions, so was hoping to be able to have them show up on mouseover.

The gist of the code is:

```
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node('A', name='Node A', description='This is node A')
G.add_node('B', name='Node B', description='This is node B')

G.add_edge('A', 'B')

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)

col_a='#000000'
col_b='#111111'
colours={'A':col_a, 'B':col_b}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=[colors[node] for node in G.nodes()], with_labels=False, node_size=2700)

node_labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'name')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels=node_labels, font_size=9)

ax.set_facecolor("#666666")
mpld3.save_html(fig,"Skill tree.html")
```

I had some help in the comments that has since been deleted, the code that was given is below, but it doesn't provide the mouseover descriptions. So I'm just putting it here in case it's easily fixable and someone can help from it:

```
class NodeDescription(plugins.PluginBase):
    JAVASCRIPT = """
    mpld3.register_plugin("node_description", NodeDescription);
    NodeDescription.prototype = Object.create(mpld3.Plugin.prototype);
    NodeDescription.prototype.constructor = NodeDescription;
    function NodeDescription(fig, props){
        mpld3.Plugin.call(this, fig, props);
    };

    NodeDescription.prototype.draw = function(){
        var tooltip = this.props.tooltip;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.fig.axes.length; i++){
            var ax = this.fig.axes[i];
            ax.elements.push(mpld3.path_tooltip(tooltip));
        }
    }
    """

    def __init__(self, points, tooltip, **kwargs):
        self.points = points
        self.tooltip = tooltip
        self.metadata = kwargs

    def get_dict(self):
        x = [point[0] for point in self.points]
        y = [point[1] for point in self.points]
        return {'type': 'node_description', 'x': x, 'y': y, 'tooltip': self.tooltip, 'metadata': self.metadata}

    def get_javascript(self):
        return self.JAVASCRIPT


node_positions = [(x, y) for x, y in pos.values()]
node_descriptions = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'description')
plugins.connect(fig, NodeDescription(node_positions, tooltip=list(node_descriptions.values())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really encourage you to look into [Bokeh](https://bokeh.org/). It's a python library that has a ton of options and does exactly what you need.

I wrote a **very** basic code to render the graph, but know that you can really make it your own and change the nodes' and edges' colors & size based on attributes.

First you need to install it:

```
pip install bokeh
```

And here's the code:

```py
import networkx as nx

from bokeh.models import Circle
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import from_networkx
from bokeh.io import save

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node('A', name='Node A', description='This is node A')
G.add_node('B', name='Node B', description='This is node B')

G.add_edge('A', 'B')

# there are multiple positioning algos, you should play around with them
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)

HOVER_TOOLTIPS = [
            ("name", "@name"),
            ("description", "@description"),
        ]

# Create a plot — set dimensions, toolbar, and title
plot = figure(tooltips=HOVER_TOOLTIPS,
                tools="pan,wheel_zoom,save,reset", active_scroll='wheel_zoom', title='my plot', sizing_mode='stretch_both', width=1000, height=1000)

network_graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=10, center=(0, 0), pos=pos)
network_graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=50, fill_color='blue')

plot.renderers.append(network_graph)
output_file(filename=str('test.html'))
save(plot, filename='test.html')
```

And here some pictures of the result:

Without the mouse hover:
[image]

Then when you hover with your mouse:
[image]

Comment: First, thank you so much, this is exactly what I need. 2 things I haven't been able to work out from the link you send and I hope you might be able to help/point me towards - 1. is it possible/how would I get the name property of the nodes to display on the node? 2. how can I get the colours of the nodes to be set individually, either from the dictionary I had before or from adding a new thing to the nodes denoting it are the 2 things I can think, but I can't work out how to implement it?

Comment: I've worked out how to colour the nodes, just labeling them on the graph that I'm unsure on now

Comment: you want the name to be shown whether there is a mouse over or not?

Comment: Yes, ideally just displayed on the node itself, but if not just at all would be great

Comment: i actually dont know how to do it :\

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help you have given - it's been really useful and I really appreciate it